# Firebase Sales Performance Report

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, web-analytics

Can we get Sales Performance Report like Google Analytics in the Firebase Analytics?

I've checked the Firebase document (within ecommerce_purchase event [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317499?hl=en)), however, I can't find anything similar to the [Sales Performance report](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#report/conversions-ecommerce-sales-performance-beta/a54516992w87479473p92320289/) of GA where we get Transaction ID and within Transaction ID all the products information.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not have E-commerce reports. You can only see the e-commerce events that you have fired. If you wish to see the E-commerce reports like Sales performance etc, you need to link Firebase with Google Analytics.

Read it here : [How to link GA and Firebase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317479)

Comment: Hi Tushar,                                                                                         Thanks for your answer.                                                                        
The link you provided shows how to see Firebase report on the Google Analytics Interface, however, don't provide any information about required E-commerce report. I am assuming you meant using the old way to get an E-commerce Report i.e. creating web property and within that web property create new app view, please let me know whether my assumption is right or not?